# Toolbar Selected Tab Text Color Android

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I am trying to set custom color for Tab text in one of my android application but instead change its setting white color for it. Other tab text is going changed but not changing only for selected Tab.

My Style for Tab is like below

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText"
        parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
       <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#000</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColorLite</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textPageCount</item>
    </style>
```

I am using it in My Layout XML is like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can see I have set black color for selected tab in style but its showing only white color. Let me know what I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this following code:

Add this style into your `TabLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Add this style into your **Style.xml**

```
 <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <!--<item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>-->
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/appcolor</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">10dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">10dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/lightblue</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/appcolor</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

Another way to change programmatically:

```
 tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: @Priya Add your style like this `style="@style/MineCustomTabText"` inside your tablayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tab_text_color.xml` in drawable folder like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/text_tab_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected" />
</selector>
```

then in style.xml do this and check

```
<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_color</item>
    ...
</style>
```